# ECONNRESET proxy error between dev server and API

Tags: node.js, sockets, debugging, proxy, econnreset

When I run my development server, I get the following error.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /graphql from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3010.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

It is preventing me from proxying any requests from the development server to the API.

After debugging, I realized it was not a problem with the code because my colleague and I are working from the same repo and he does not have this error. Also, sometimes if I restart my terminal the error will go away before it comes back again.

Would greatly appreciate guidance on what is the root of this issue and how I can resolve it.